# How to change UI Button label in controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

It's sound simple but I'm going nuts here, and I'm simply trying to change the label name in the **controller.js** file

Here is what I'm doing here, any help?

Component:

```html
<ui:button aura:id = "Btn1" label="Get Password" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" press="{!c.handleClick}" />
```

Controller JS:

```js
var currentBoatTypeChoice = component.find("Btn1");//.get("v.label");
currentBoatTypeChoice.set('v.label','New Label');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently tried to change a label of `<ui:button>` by myself using `component.set()` method:

```js
component.find('Btn1').set('v.label', 'New Label');
```

and it absolutely works. Can you please provide an error message, because it should work and probably the issue is caused by something else?

> Since of API version 47.0 `<ui:button>` is **deprecated**. Use `<lightning:button>`, `<lightning:buttonIcon>`, or `<lightning:buttonIconStateful>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute and put it in the button's label. This way, you can simply modify the attribute's value in the js, and it will change in the button as well.

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="buttonLabel" type="String" default="Get password" />
<ui:button aura:id = "Btn1" label="{!v.buttonLabel}" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" press="{!c.handleClick}" />
```

Controller.js

```
component.set("v.buttonLabel", "New label");
```